# Pass React component as prop to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass complete parent component as props to its child component. Whereas, while trying to pass some data from parent to child, I imported the child into parent. So, how can I do that now in other way around? Any suggestions? As I want to re render Parent component upon some state change of child component.
Example Added:

```
// Parent Component
import B from './B.js';

class A extends React.Component{
constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
         this.state = {
                 showB: false
         }
    }
onClick = () =>{
this.setState({ 
            showB: true
            });
}
render(){
return(
{
 this.state.showB ? <B /> : 
<div>
<Button onClick={this.onClick}>VIEW B </Button>
</div>
<h1>Some text</h1>
)
}
}

// Child Component

class B extends React.Component{
constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
         this.state = {
                 showA: false
         }
    }
onClick = () =>{
this.setState({ 
            showA: true
            });
}
render(){
return(
{
 this.state.showA ? <A /> : 
<div>
<Button onClick={this.onClick}>Back</Button>
</div>
<h1>Back to Component A</h1>
)
}

}
```

Comment: If the child needs to inform its parent of something, pass a callback from parent to child as a prop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe child does not need to inform anything. I have a Back button in my child component. Clicking on it, I just want to render Parent Component again. Because, some how initially clicking on Parent took me to child component.

Comment: What do you mean *"maybe"*? Could you provide a more concrete context?

Comment: As said by @jonrsharpe you can use callback But If you just want to render parent component on clicking of button,Then  you can use BrowserRouter of react-router-dom

Comment: @jonrsharpe Example added. this is desired behavior I want to have. So I was wondering how can I access Parent component i.e. A  inside child component. According to my understanding, as I am just learning react. I was assuming, Maybe  I need to pass parent component as prop to its child component.

Comment: You can definitely do that by passing a callback down. Also I'd strongly advise you to consider using more structured formatting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you demonstrate with example?

Comment: Hi Meana, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to toggle between parent and child component, I recommend passing down the callback function from parent to child and access that function to navigate back to the parent component.

Your parent component should be this,

```
class A extends React.Component{
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      showB: false
    }
  }

  onClick = () =>{
    this.setState({ 
      showB: !this.state.showB    //This will negate the existing state
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <>  //use Fragments / div here 
      {
        this.state.showB ? 
        <B click={this.onClick}/> //Provide callabck function here
        : 
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.onClick}>VIEW B </button>
          <h1>Some text</h1>
        </div>
      }
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

You child component should be this,

```
class B extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return( 
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.click}>Back</button>
        <h1>Back to Component A</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fgiayv)